# Linear dependance of vectors

Tags: vectors

I am not very proficient with mathematics. I have the following question.

When do we say two vectors are linearly independent, in X-Y coordinate system (2-D case)?

I read that any two non parallel vectors are linearly independent in 2-D space.

But from various other contexts I find that the necessary and sufficient condition for two vectors to be linearly independent is that they must be orthogonal. And, this appeals to me to be true conceptually. I am interested only in two dimensional vectors.

Any clarification in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Well two vectors $v_1, v_2$ are linearly independent if $av_1 + bv_2 = 0$ is only satisfied when both $a,b$ are zero. But to say that they are linearly dependent means that there are scalars $a,b$ not all zero so that $av_1 + bv_2 = 0$. If $a \neq 0$, then $v_1 = -\frac{bv_2}{a}$. Or if $b$ is non-zero, you can deduce one is the multiple of another. This is the definition of linear (in)dependence, so that's why you get two vectors are linearly independent if they're not a multiple of each other.

Answer (score 1):

A vector (in 2-D) is said to be linearly **dependent** when one can be obtained from the other by multiplying by a **scalar** or a number. For example, $(1,0)$ and $(3,0)$ are linearly dependent because you can obtain latter by multiplying former by 3 or obtain former by multiplying latter by $\frac{1}{3}$.

So, they are linearly **independent** when they are *not* linearly dependent.

By formal definition, a subset $S$ of a vector space $V$ is said to be linearly dependent if there exist a finite number of distinct vectors, $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ in $S$ and scalars $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n$ not all zero, such that $a_1x_1+a_2x_2+...+a_nx_n = 0$. In this case, S is said to be linearly dependent.

A subset $S$ of a vector space $V$ is said to be linearly independent if $S$ is not linearly dependent.

So, we can also say that a set of vectors (in any dimension) are linearly dependent if a vector in it can be written as linear combination of the other vectors in set. Whereas they are linearly independent if this statement does not hold.

I don't know how much you have studied linear algebra so far, but if you are interested you can study from Linear Algebra by Gilbert Strang (MIT OCW has Strang's lectures as well). It is good for beginners and Linear Algebra is very interesting subject. Good Luck!

Comment: My problem arose when I saw Maxwell was insistent on orthogonality of two vectors so that they are independent, in deriving his equation of distribution of speeds of molecules in an ideal gas at equilibrium.Why should he insist on orthogonality?

Comment: When two vectors are orthogonal, it geometrically means that they are perpendicular to each other. So, no vector is parallel to the other one, which further implies that one can't be obtained by multiplying the other by a scalar (remember - scalar multiplication to vector only changes magnitude not direction). Thus, the two vectors will be linearly independent... About the derivation by Maxwell, I didn't study about equation of distribution of speed of molecules, as I only studied pure math and applied math, but I hope you are able to understand how orthogonality implies linear independence...

Comment: I understand that orthogonal vectors are linearly independent and my conviction is that it is a necessary and sufficient condition for linear independence. (Maxwell stresses on orthogonality in his derivation. Let us not delve further into that but concentrate only on linear dependence).

Comment: I understand that orthogonal vectors are linearly independent and my conviction is that it is a necessary and sufficient condition for linear independence. (Maxwell stresses on orthogonality in his derivation. Let us not delve further into that but concentrate only on linear dependence).  A set of 3 or more vectors that form a loop add up to a zero vector. Any of the component vectors say Vi   and the zero vector are linearly independent, since the sum of a non zero scalar multiple of Vi and the zero vector is a non zero vector. But, can Vi and sigma Vi be linearly independent?

Comment: I am sorry, I did not get what you are trying to ask... Can you explain it again? Also use Latex to write mathematical symbols and equations (You may refer http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html)...

Comment: I tried the link. It is not useful. I wrote the equations. but nothing happened. They remained as I wrote them.  In words I wrote what I thought was simple. Obviously it is not, as you did not follow it. I'm not conversant with using computer much. I do work with MS Word and GeoGebra but nothing more than that. Here also I find it difficult to communicate as I am relatively new to this site.

Comment: I understand your problem. Latex is nothing but formatting code, especially useful for writing mathematical text.  About the link: You need need to draw the symbols in the space where it says "Draw here", the database will find you Latex code corresponding to it. You have to choose the appropriate code. It will appear as something like - \mathbb{R}, for example. You have to add dollar symbol before and after the code and it appears like - $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: About your question: If any set of vectors contain zero vector then it becomes linearly dependent because zero cannot be expressed uniquely as linear combination of given set of vectors. I am not able to understand rest of your query. So, if you explain a little more, perhaps my answer would be more clear.

Comment: You may refer this tutorial help for writing math equations when writing here questions http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: This link is useful. Let me try it out. My question is this:$ \sum_1^n{a_iV-i}=0\$. V_i and 0 are vectors. Now we add a component vector V_1, to this zero (or loop) vector. We get a finite non zero vector V_i. That shows V_i and the zero vector are linearly independent. But, since V_i is a component vector of the zero vector, V_i and zero must be linearly dependent vectors. It is this contradiction that is bothering me.

Comment: Let us restrict to a set of three linearly independent vectors $v_1, v
_2$ and $v_3$ for the sake of simplicity. So, $a_1v_1+a_2v_2+a_3v_3=0 \implies a_1=a_2=a_3=0$, by definition of linear independence. Now you are adding say $v_1$ to the equation, then $(a_1+1)v_1+a_2v_2+a_3v_3=0+v_1 \implies v_1=v_1$. There is no contradiction here.